# Strange comment error message

Tags: support, comments

I tried putting this comment on a bad SO answer

> Leaving an answer with only a link and no description is not going to be useful to the user. If the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. It is also just giving the user another hoop to jump through to find their answer. So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.

But I got the error

> Comments can't contain that content

I am not really sure what content it can't contain, especially because I have used this comment before as part of one of my userscripts

Comment: I guess the URL shortener is the problem.

Comment: Well works on meta.

Comment: But not on SO @MartinSmith. Just verified. Editing out the link resolves it.

Comment: @Bart - Just tried as well. Pretty sure your first comment is correct.

Comment: Huh, weird. It's definitely the short URL because I see that it's been blacklisted, but if you were able to post this comment in the past, then perhaps it was blacklisted only recently (i.e. this week).

Comment: In which case, cue "why is the error message so vague?!?!?!"

Comment: In light of the recent spam bombings, SE probably has blocked a bunch of URL shorteners temporarily.

Comment: Leaving an answer with only a link and no description is not going to be useful to the user. If the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. It is also just giving the user another hoop to jump through to find their answer. So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.

Comment: Yep, works on Meta - although you would have to be crazy to try to sell handbags to a hoard of people who are obsessed with moderation :D

Answer (score 2):

Same "bug" as this one: [I am getting the message "can't save your About Me field with that content." when trying to update my About Me profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196240/152859)

As Anna wrote there:

> It looks like we're blacklisting goo.gl links on Stack Overflow now

And then she went on and removed the blacklist. Comment away! :)

Comment: Now that I know how to put Community Bump out of its stride...

Comment: @Bill sorry, what?

Comment: The question was bumped by Community. I now know that if I Upvote an Answer, Community won't go for bumping the question again. So I Upvoted. Sorry for being cryptic.

Comment: @Bill oh lol! Didn't notice it got the auto-bump (can see now as it's active today without any real activity)... thanks for the vote! ;)