# I am getting the message "can't save your About Me field with that content." when trying to update my About Me profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I'm removing some content from my About Me profile that is clearly just noise, and when I went to save the profile, I received the following message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - can't save your About Me field with that content.

The vague message makes me think I triggered some kind of content filter, but it just doesn't seem like me to post something so unruly.

As a test, I just removed one letter and tried clicking "Save Profile" just to see if I could discover the problem.  It failed, so this must be something new that has a bug in it that prevents me from changing my profile.

Comment: Sure, sure, we all can see through your plan of banking 70K+ rep on SE in anticipation of spamming us at *just* the right moment...

Comment: You just wait @jonsca, all that spam I've been sitting on all these years is just gonna come flooding out so fast that not even Jon Skeet will know what to do. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like we're blacklisting goo.gl links on Stack Overflow now. Not sure when that went in or why, but that's the most likely culprit since you're using those links in your profile.

**Update:** the blacklist has been removed, so edit away!

Comment: if we're blacklisting URL shortners then I fully support this move, could we roll this out to the entire internet, thanks

Comment: I was using them primarily because I was using literally every single character allowed in my profile, so using the shorter links allow me to pack in more information. I'd be interested to know if there's a safer version of shorter links.  As an aside, it does seem a little odd to blacklist those in one's profile page. I can see doing so in posts; however. Maybe this is just an oversight?

Comment: I'm personally against shortener blacklists, so I'm asking around to see what's what. That said, there's no way to set up separate blacklists for different inputs on the site. It's an all-or-nothing kinda deal.

Comment: Isn't it ironic you're (the team) using goo.gl yourself, e.g. for the post ban message? :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That got changed a while back. It now points to the help center instead. But otherwise, it would've been quite ironic. :)

Comment: Great! There is/was feature request asking to do exactly this, let me look for it... [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183285/152859) - short memory on my side. :(